# Wrap text using zsh bindkey

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, key-binding

I'm trying to make a keyboard shortcut which wraps the current command in the terminal like this:
`($current_command && say done) || say error`

I've got it partially working with:

```bsh
# ~/.zshrc
bindkey -s "^B" "&& say done) || say error"
```

I can't seem to figure out how to insert the `(` at the start of the command currently in the terminal. Is this possible?

Comment: Hm, if this wasn't just an example and your goal is to check the exit code of the command, you might also consider to set the right prompt accordingly. I use e.g. `RPS1=' %(?..%? )` which prints the exit code of the previous command if it was not successful. See _PROMPT SEQUENCES_ in `man zshmisc` for details.

Comment: It's not just an example, I am using this code. It's from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9422/333759
I like having an audio notification rather than just visual so I can work on other things while waiting on long running tests or builds.

The error behaviour seems to work fine, what case do you think would break it?

Comment: I understand that point that an audible feedback might be better suited. But sorry, what "error behaviour" do you mean here in your question: "The error behaviour seems to work fine, what case do you think would break it?"

Comment: I mean when there's an error it'll run `say error` because the process returns a non-zero code. I thought that's what you were getting at with the RPS1 stuff, that I'd need to consider something else to handle all errors?

Comment: No, no, I see no problem with your `say error` approach. I mentioned the `RPS1` possibility just because I though maybe it is saving you from hitting `^B` in some cases. Of course, sometimes the errorcode gives more info why something went wrong (depending on the program), but `|| say error` will be fine for catching all errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first possibility which comes to my mind is to use a zle widget with which you have full control over the command line -- *zle* is the *zsh command line editor*.

Look at this code snippet:

```
talktome() {
  BUFFER="($BUFFER"
  BUFFER="$BUFFER && say done) || say error"
  (( CURSOR++ ))
}
```

Pretty basic without any bells or whistles, but more easy to understand that way. `$BUFFER` holds the current command line, and all this code does is add a `(` at the beginning and the other stuff at the end. The only convenience I included it to shift the cursor one position to the right so that is stands at the end end of the typed command. (This is needed because we added the opening brace.)

Now, you just have to announce to *zsh* that this function should act as a widget and assign a key binding, like so

```
zle -N talktome
bindkey "^B" talktome
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a million!